# PostgreSQL update JSONB column from JSON string to Array of JSON objects

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I am trying to update the value of a JSONB column from a JSON string like :

```
{"fruit":"apple", "color":"blue"}
```

to an array of JSON objects like :

```
[{"fruit":"apple"}, {"color":"blue"}]
```

I tried the following command :

```
UPDATE table_name SET data = json_build_array(data::JSONB);
```

It however gave me the following :

```
[{"fruit":"apple","color":"blue"}]
```

What can I use to get separate JSON objects in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can access each key-value pair in the JSON object using `json_each`, and then aggregate the results into an array:

```
update table_name set data = (select json_agg(json_build_object(v.key, v.value)) 
                              from json_each(data) v)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hdvyrVze).